# Detecting changes in text

Tags: java

I would like to know the name of a Java library which is able to detect changes in text in two text files (or Strings).
I want to detect the changes on saving a java source file and ultimately want to know the name of the method on which a changes was performed.

Comment: FYI there sometimes aren't libraries for things. Your questions asks for the name of library when instead it should probably be asking how to detect changes in text files. Also, are you assuming these are source code files like .java files? Your questions seems to imply this.

Comment: I am looking to detect changes in a .java source file currently. I don't necessarily need the library I am willing to write it myself however I need to know an efficient algorithm.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the details of the change aren't important (just that the files have changed) then you can use a hash (such as MD5) to detect that the change.

Otherwise you should use one of the diff utilities like [this](http://code.google.com/p/google-diff-match-patch/) and then pair that with a source info library like [QDox](http://qdox.codehaus.org/). You could use the diff utility to determine where the changes are, and then use QDox to determine the method start/end lines that are around the changes.